# Filtering a list of strings by combining duplicate values, as well as appending a duplicate value

Tags: python

I currently have a list of strings that looks something like:

```
"a 05/13/22 apple"        
"a 05/13/22 apple"        
"b 05/13/22 apple"        
"b 05/13/22 apple"        
"c 05/13/22 apple"        
"c 05/13/22 apple"        
"a 05/27/22 strawberry"   
"a 05/27/22 strawberry"   
"b 05/27/22 strawberry"   
"b 05/27/22 strawberry"   
"c 05/27/22 strawberry"   
"c 05/27/22 strawberry"   
"a 07/29/22 banana"       
"a 07/29/22 banana"       
"b 07/29/22 banana"       
"b 07/29/22 banana"       
"c 07/29/22 banana"       
"c 07/29/22 banana"
```

I've split the strings into separate values, and am trying to achieve an output similar to this:

```
6 occurrences found for apple 
05/13/22 apple [a,b,c]

6 occurrences found for strawberry
05/27/22 strawberry [a,b,c]

6 occurrences found for banana
07/29/22 banana [a,b,c]
```

I've attempted to loop over the values, as so

```
fruit_exists = []
pexists = []
pfruit, pdate, pletters = '','',[]
for instance in fruit_info:
        letter, date, fruit = instance.split()
        if fruit not in fruit_exists:
            fruit_exists.append(fruit)    
        if pdate == '':
            pfruit = fruit
            pdate = date
        if pdate+pfruit not in pexists:
            if letter not in pletters:
                pletters.append(letter)
            if pdate != date:
                print(f'{pdate} - {pfruit} for {", ".join(pletters)}')
                pexists.append(pdate+pfruit)
                pfruit = fruit
                pdate = date
                pletters = []
    print(f'{pdate} - {pfruit} for {", ".join(pletters)}')
```

As well as other iterations of this for loop, however I think I may be approaching the problem incorrectly, as I do not seem to retrieve the correct values when trying to solve the issue this way

Comment: so you are grouping by same (fruit, date) combination and counting the occurrences and the which {a, b, c} they occur with?  Your example data leaves some questions because all the dates are same for each fruit.

Comment: also, are you comfortable/proficient using `dictionaries` in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are about 1000 ways to do this, depending on your skills.  Here is one that uses 2 dictionaries and some basic python.

```
data = ['a 05/13/22 apple',        
        'a 05/13/22 apple',        
        'b 05/13/22 apple',        
        'b 05/13/22 apple',        
        'c 05/13/22 apple',        
        'c 05/13/22 apple',        
        'a 05/27/22 strawberry',   
        'a 05/27/22 strawberry',   
        'b 05/27/22 strawberry',   
        'b 05/27/22 strawberry',   
        'c 05/27/22 strawberry',   
        'c 05/27/22 strawberry',   
        'a 07/29/22 banana',       
        'a 07/29/22 banana',       
        'b 07/29/22 banana',       
        'b 07/29/22 banana',       
        'c 07/29/22 banana',       
        'c 07/29/22 banana'] 

count_dict = dict()  # to hold the count
ltr_dict =   dict()  # to hold the set of letters
for item in data:
    # split it up...
    ltr, dt, fruit = item.strip().split()
    # get the fruit/dt tuple from the keys, if not there bring back 0
    count =count_dict.get((fruit, dt), 0)
    # put it in the dictionary, incremented by 1
    count_dict[(fruit, dt)] = count + 1 
    # get the set of letters currently seen, or in none, an empty set
    ltrs = ltr_dict.get((fruit, dt), set())
    # add the letter to the set, and put it back in...
    ltrs.add(ltr)
    ltr_dict[(fruit, dt)] = ltrs

# produces these results:
print(count_dict)
print(ltr_dict)

# we can then iterate through the keys of the dictionary to get a nicer format:

for f,d in count_dict.keys():
    print(f'have count of {count_dict.get((f,d))} for {f, d} in letters:')
    print(','.join(sorted(ltr_dict.get((f,d)))))
```

##### Output:

```
{('apple', '05/13/22'): 6, ('strawberry', '05/27/22'): 6, ('banana', '07/29/22'): 6}
{('apple', '05/13/22'): {'b', 'c', 'a'}, ('strawberry', '05/27/22'): {'b', 'c', 'a'}, ('banana', '07/29/22'): {'b', 'c', 'a'}}
have count of 6 for ('apple', '05/13/22') in letters:
a,b,c
have count of 6 for ('strawberry', '05/27/22') in letters:
a,b,c
have count of 6 for ('banana', '07/29/22') in letters:
a,b,c
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I wasn't aware of the 'get' portion of this, and reading it makes sense. I will try to implement it this way and work with it further - thank you again!

Comment: Great. It is customary to up-vote Any of the answers that were helpful to you, and if the issue is resolved, close it out by hitting the checkmark next to one of them as the accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
fruits = dict()
for instance in fruit_info:
        letter, date, fruit = instance.split(' ')
        if fruit not in fruits or fruits[fruit][1] != date:            
            fruits[fruit] = [1, date, [letter]]    
        else:
            fruits[fruit][0] += 1
            if letter not in fruits[fruit][2]:
                fruits[fruit][2].append(letter)

for key in fruits:
    my_list = fruits[key]
    print(f"{my_list[0]} occurrences found for {key}")
    print(f"{my_list[1]} {key} {fruits[fruit][2]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have new entries where the dates are not all the same, this implementation will take care of any amount of fruits!

**Step 1** We will use a fruit dictionary to store our values after parsing the list where `fruit_list` is the list you gave above:

```py
fruit_dict = {}
for item in fruit_list:
    letter, date, fruit = item.split()
    if fruit not in fruit_dict:
        fruit_dict[fruit] = {
            'letters': [letter],
            'dates': [date],
            'occurences': 1
        }
    else:
        fruit_dict[fruit]['letters'].append(letter) if letter not in fruit_dict[fruit]['letters'] else None
        fruit_dict[fruit]['dates'].append(date) if date not in fruit_dict[fruit]['dates'] else None
        fruit_dict[fruit]['occurences'] += 1
```

**Step 2** Then print our values:

```py
for fruit in fruit_dict.keys():
    letters = fruit_dict[fruit]['letters']
    dates = str(fruit_dict[fruit]['dates'])
    occurences = fruit_dict[fruit]['occurences']
    print(f"{occurences} occurences found for {fruit}\n{dates} {fruit} {letters}\n")
```

Comment: Thank you! I do expect to have different date values on rare circumstance, so this does help a bunch. I believe I'm on the right track now

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach but using Counter. The code creates a dictionary which has this skeleton: `{fruit: {date: Counter()}}`

```
d = {}

# your_list is your list of strings
for i in your_list:
    char, date, fruit = i.strip().split()
    if key := d.get(fruit):
        key[date] = key[date] + Counter(char)
    else:
        d[fruit] = {date: Counter(char)}

for i in d:
    c: Counter = list(d[i].values())[0]
    print(i, list(d[i])[0], ", total", c.total(), 'occurrences:',
          *[f"{i[0]}={i[1]}," for i in c.most_common()])
```

Output:

```
apple 05/13/22 , total 6 occurrences: a=2, b=2, c=2,
strawberry 05/27/22 , total 6 occurrences: a=2, b=2, c=2,
banana 07/29/22 , total 6 occurrences: a=2, b=2, c=2,
```